# XCode: keyboard shortcut to jump to editor window?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xcode

In XCode, I have my project window active (pressed command - 0). Now after I have selected the file I want to edit, it opens in the editor window, but the Project window still remains the active one. Is there a keyboard shortcut to jump to editor window?

Answer (score 0):

You can cycle through the areas of the XCode window by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>.